# Customizing GridView column borders for each column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, coding-style, border

I have several columns and I want to have borders on the left and on the right of some like this:

| column1 column2 | column3 column4 |

If I specify the border in the `ItemStyle`, it shows on both side and won't render the absence of column between columns 1 and 2 and column 3 and 4.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a style in your CSS like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.column_style_left
    {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
    }    
    td.column_style_right
    {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }    
</style>
```

Then assign it to the `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="column_style_left" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- whatever you want here -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="column_style_right" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- whatever you want here -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- whatever you want here -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="column_style_right" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- whatever you want here -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Which will produce:

```
| column1 column2 | column3 column4 |
```

You can change the style to match what you need like right side, left or top, etc...

Just make a unique style for each of the columns that differ.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a style like

```
  table td:nth-child(2n) {
        padding:2px 8px;
        border-right:1px solid black;
    }
```

Check out [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MWyQU/)